# How can I get an idea of what is the volume of the air displaced by an object totally immersed in it?

Tags: buoyancy

My specific problem is that I can't figure out what object displaces more air, a rigid closed container or a similar container that is opened. 
For example,  let's think in two similar bottles with rigid walls, one of them is sealed with its cap (the pressure inside it is that of the atmospheric pressure when the bottle was sealed) and the other uncapped. Then, I'd like to know the buoyant forces acting on both of them and, in accordance with Archimedes this force depends on the volume displaced by the object. Because I find too hard to ¨visualize¨ which of the two bottles will displace a greater amount of air or if the air displaced would be the same in both cases, I began by thinking on what would happen in water, I mean, which of them when submerged in water would displaced more fluid. I've actually made the experiment (with two plastic bottles, though), but I didn´t notice a remarkable difference in the rise of water. So, someone could tell me a way to see which of my containers would displace more air? Please, I've read here too many questions of buoyancy however none of them could help me with my question.

Comment: The closed one because of the lid.

Comment: Then the closed have a greater  buoyant force, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes in practice it is. With  thin walls it might be negligible, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of air the situation is simple. Both the open and close bottles have the same mass of air inside if the pressure is the same. In case of water the analogy fails. There would be some volume of the bottle filled with liquid due to the hydrostatic pressure of the liquid colmumn above. The pressure of the gas would increase however slightly.
When there is a cap, the pressure inside would not change. Not surprised that a simple experiment would not show the difference

Comment: In the case of air, as both of them have the same mass, can I say that its apparent weight is the same?

Comment: In the case of air, as both of them have the same mass, I could assure that its weight (m*g) is the same, but what about its apparent weight? I know that to answer this question I need to use both the weigth and buoyant force but I still have troubles realizing whether the buoyant force is greater in one of two cases or if  it remains the same in both of them,

Comment: @Sama buoyancy force can be different if the volume or mass change (or both). In air neither change. Immersed in water the mass can change if water enters the  open bottle.